# Creating a dynamic view with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a database that creates a new table for transactions every month. So there are tables like `TRANS201811`, `TRANS201812`, `TRANS201901`, etc. I need a view that shows all of these transactions in the view. Below is the dynamic SQL I've written that accomplishes what I am trying to do. However, I'm trying to see if there is a more efficient way of writing this. Thanks!

```
declare @sql as varchar(max) = (
            SELECT ltrim(stuff((
            SELECT ' UNION SELECT ACCOUNT, AMOUNT, GL_FROM, GL_TO, INIT_ACCNT, LOGGED, TRAN_WHEN FROM ' + cast(t.table_schema + '.' + t.table_name AS VARCHAR(max)) + ' '
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'softwareadmin'
                            AND (TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TRANS20%')
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 6, N'')))

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: The more efficient way is to stop creating different tables and instead add the year and month information as columns to a single table containing all transactions.

Comment: Do you have a reason for doing it this way? Seems highly irregular...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is done automatically by the software vendor and is out of my control.

Comment: The _traditional_ approach is to create empty tables covering transactions until your expected retirement date, e.g. `Trans205912`, and create a view that incorporates all of those tables. Let the vendor write into the appropriate monthly table each month. After that, it's not your responsibility. <Tongue firmly in cheek./> (Using [synonyms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) may provide a way to create a view that references "future" tables that can be "connected" as they become live. Use an empty table as a placeholder.)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a  simple view that shows all of them:

```
CREATE VIEW AS transactionViews
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND [TABLE_NAME] LIKE 'TRANS20%'
```

Comment: Your view will provide one row for each table the OP is interested in, but it doesn't provide a means to get data from those tables. The OP wants to create a view that allows them to `select` data from all of the transaction tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stored procedure that uses dynamic sql to alter the view each month, then schedule a monthly job in SQLAgent to execute the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC [usp_updateTransactionsView] AS BEGIN

declare @sql as varchar(max) = (
            SELECT ltrim(stuff((
            SELECT ' UNION 
            SELECT ACCOUNT, AMOUNT, GL_FROM, GL_TO, INIT_ACCNT, LOGGED, TRAN_WHEN FROM ' + cast(t.table_schema + '.' + t.table_name AS VARCHAR(max)) + ' '
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'softwareadmin'
                            AND (TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TRANS20%')
            FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 6, N'')))

declare @alterViewSQL as varchar(max) = CONCAT('ALTER VIEW vw_transactions AS ',@sql)

exec(@alterViewSQL)
END
```